# Store numpad key input in x and y variables

Tags: c

I have an external Numpad that has numbers from 0-9 and letters from A-D.

I want to store numbers from 0-9 in x and y as coordinates. When I press A(which equ. 10) I want to draw a point.

The problem is I can not figure out how to store first key in x and second key in y. As soon as I press a key it assigns both x and y the same numbers.

I have tried many different if-statements but it always assigns both x and y same number.

```
int counter=0;
numPad[16]={1,4,7,14,2,5,8,0,3,6,9,15,10,11,12,13};

          if(numPad[key]<10){
             x=numPad[key];  
             x*=16;
             counter++;
          }
          if(counter>0 && numPad[key]<10){
             y=numPad[key];  
             y*=8;            
          }
          if(numPad[key]==10){
             LCD_DrawPoint(x,y,WHITE);
             counter=0;     
          }
```

Comment: You should post your entire code, and the values of X and Y after running the program. It's impossible to find the problem without at least defining all the variables you used first, like x and y, and what their types are. If they are pointers then I think you have your answer.

Comment: int x =0; and same for y. I do not think there is a problem with other prats of the code, I think the problem is it is not saving first keypress in x before moving on to y.

Comment: value < 10? check! Store to x. check! increment counter. check! value < 10 and counter incremented? check! Store to y, too... Wrong... You need to figure out an if/else to only store to either x or y...

Comment: @Laros That might be so, but it's good practice to provide an MVE. Anyway, you check if `numPad[key] < 10`, but only call `LCD_DrawPoint` if `numPad[key] == 10` - `< 10` and `== 10` exclude eachother, this will never work. If you input anything other than 10, this will assign the correct values to x and y, but will never call drawpoint. If you input 10, the values of x and y will be the same (0, since they are never assigned) - This is why I asked you to provide inputs and outputs, and an MVE in general.

Comment: @zimano thank you for you answer. I'm not sure if I understand it correctly tho.  My thinking here was following: If I press A on numpad which = 10 the program should output a dot. So I though if I write numPad[key] < 10 I only include numbers from 0-9.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Can you please explain why is it wrong? Shouldn't it call y only if counter is > 0 and if I press number between 0-9?

Comment: @Laros Fe2O3 is wrong and you can disregard their comment. You have to understand that `if(numPad[key] < 10)` and `if(numPad[key] == 10)` cannot be true at the same time. Therefore, you cannot assign both the value and draw the point with your current program. This is what you need to fix.

Comment: @Laros It's not clear to me what you're asking. Your comment introduces new code that isn't present in your original question too. Perhaps you could provide the full code, or narrow down your question a bit better.

Comment: @Zimano I'm sorry about that,  I changed name of the array but did not update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statements for setting x and y, and drawing the point are mutually exclusive. `if(numPad[key] < 10)` and `if(numPad[key] == 10)` cannot be true at the same time. I'm not sure why you're making that comparison, but I think it is to cap the max possible input value at 9 or something. In the example below, we cap the max possible value of numPad[key] at 9, assign it to X and Y, then draw the point. The counter is useless here, but I kept it in because you had it in your original code.

```
int counter = 0;
numPad[16] = { 1,4,7,14,2,5,8,0,3,6,9,15,10,11,12,13 };

int someValue = numPad[key];

if(someValue > 9) {
    someValue = 9;
}

x = someValue * 16;
y = someValue * 8;  

LCD_DrawPoint(x,y,WHITE);
counter=0;
```

You could provide a minimum verifiable example next time as this will allow us to help you better.

Comment: I will look into this one adn try it, thank you!

Comment: I think I see where the misunderstanding is. On my numPad 'A' holds the value of 10. So in my code when I write if(numPad[key] == 10), it means if I press 'A' draw this circle with x and y coordinates. Problem I had was when I pressed one key between 0-9 to assign 'x' a value and then I pressed again to assign a different value to 'y', they both ended up with same value or its completeley ignorde the value of y. That is why I had if(numPad[key] < 10), meaning if the key is between 0-9 then do this...

Comment: Better answer if `numpad[16]` has an integer datatype perhaps? And if `counter` had a purpose?

Answer (score 0):

By not providing sufficient code, those who might try to help can/will misunderstand and not "fill in the blanks" appropriately. Below is my interpretation of your question.

```
int x = 0, y = 0, counter = 0; // is all this contained inside one function?

int numPad[16] = { // layout increases reader comprehension
     1,  4,  7, 14,
     2,  5,  8,  0,
     3,  6,  9, 15,
    10, 11, 12, 13
};

for( ;; ) {
    int key = scan_keyboard() // Not provided by OP

    int value = numPad[ key ]; // translate

    if( value < 10 ) {
        // alternately assign scaled low values to x or y
        if( !counter )
            x = 16 * value;
        else
            y = 8 * value;
        counter = !counter;
    }
    else if( value == 10 ) {
        LCD_DrawPoint( x, y, WHITE );
        x = y = counter = 0; // reset (excessive caution)
    }
}
```

Notice the use of `if/else`.